# Compress a date long ( currently 13 character) to another long with a minimal lenght

Tags: java, compression, converters

i want to generate a 13 character long Long like in an ISBN to generate an unique article ID/billing ID with a compressed date which would be converted back if needed.

Unfortunatelly date.getTime() is already 13 character long so i wanted to know if it's possible to shorten the length of the original Long.

Maybe compress is the wrong word but i don't know how to put the right word on it

Kind regards

Comment: Date.getTime() gives you number of milliseconds since 1970. What's the matter with YYYYMMDD if you just want a date ?

Comment: there're *54787* days between `1 Jan 1900` and `1 Jan 2050`; so `Int16` will be enough to encode `year month and day` in it; for `YYYYMMDD` format you have to use `Int32`

Comment: Thank you I didn't thought about it in that way, i loose some accuracy but it's shorter.